# CSS dropdown-menu: Hover does not do anything

Tags: hover, css, drop-down-menu

Short ans sweet: Why does `:hover` does not display the hidden content? I've tried everything, from `display: block:` to `#trigger a:hover`.

Here is the testcase: http://jsfiddle.net/5egvV/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Two problems:

#### 1. Wrong CSS selector

You have:

```
#trigger:hover ul ul {
```

It should be:

```
#trigger:hover ul {
```

#### 2. Wrong HTML

You have:

```
<li id="trigger"><a href="#" title="#">Mainitem 1</a></li>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

It should be:

```
<li id="trigger"><a href="#" title="#">Mainitem 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Subitem 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

`<ul>` should go into `<li>`